# Read live data from terminal python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working on a program where I am trying to check to see if there are any characters that have been typed in the terminal in real time (before ENTER or any other key is pressed).  I saw that

`result = subprocess.run(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, input=<input>)`

could potentially be used to read commands, but I was unsure how to put that in a loop so I could constantly check without requiring any input once the program is running.  Would I potentially be able to use pygame or another library similar to help?

Comment: Which operating systems? A unixlike system may work differently than windows.

Comment: On Windows, you can use `msvcrt.kbhit` to see if any keys have been hit, and `msvcrt.getch` to read them.  On LInux, you need to put the terminal into "raw" mode, using `tty.setraw`.  `pygame` can also do it, or `ncurses`.

Comment: @tdelaney Thanks! I primarily use PC, I do have the ubuntu terminal/cygwin installed though if that makes a difference.

Comment: @TimRoberts Thanks, I think I might see if ncurses can do it, if I can get raw to work on Windows that might be what I need.  Do you know if there is anything like ```msvcrt.kbhit``` that can check N times per second? Ideally I want all of the characters read at a constant rate.

Comment: If you just want all the characters as they are typed, `msvcrt.getch` blocks until the next key is pressed, so `while True:` / `ch = msvcrt.getch()` will get them all one by one.  What are you actually trying to achieve here?

Comment: @TimRoberts I'm planning on taking the characters that are on the screen and converting them to MIDI output, so so any characters on the screen would represent notes/patterns that are currently being played.  Basically a live-coding MIDI controller

Comment: Like this?  https://virtualpiano.net/  That's a little more complicated, because you will presumably want to send "note off" messages when the key is released.  None of the options mentioned here will do that.  You need to look at the Python `keyboard` module.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243131/discussion-between-stuuuve-and-tim-roberts).